# ruby hash where keys are from an array and value as a default value

Tags: ruby

I want to make a method named default_classroom. so that it takes an array of keys and a default value and returns a hash with all keys set to the default value. (Like, all students go to the same classroom. Here, students are the keys and class as a default value)

```
def default_classroom(students, default_class)
end
puts default_classroom([:jony, :marry], 8)

# should return => {jony: 8, marry: 8}
```

i did this:

```
def default_classroom(students, default_class)
    Hash[ students, default_class]
end
```

and also this:

```
def default_classroom(students, default_class)
    Hash[*students.flatten(default_class)]
end
```

but still not working. Will you please advice me, How can i complete that?

Comment: Rabby, I appreciate the greenie, but in future consider waiting  longer before selecting an answer. A rush to judgement may discourage other, possibly better answers, and is a bummer for those still preparing answers when the checkmark appears. Many SO members wait for several hours or even days.

Comment: Cary Swoveland, Thanks for your advice. But i was so excited.

Comment: You shouldn't have the Rails tag here, as this is a pure-Ruby question. Having a superfluous tag may cause some to waste time, others (who filter out Rails questions) to not see the question.

Comment: Cary Swoveland, i edited the tags section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many way to do this.  Here are three.

**#1**

```
def default_classroom(students, default_class)
  Hash[ students.product([default_class]) ]
end

students = %w[Billy-Bob, Trixie, Huck]
  #=> ["Billy-Bob", "Trixie", "Huck"]
default_class = "Roofing 101"

default_classroom(students, default_class)
  #=> {"Billy-Bob"=>"Roofing 101", "Trixie"=>"Roofing 101",
  #    "Huck"=>"Roofing 101"}
```

For Ruby versions >= 2.0, you could instead write:

```
students.product([default_class]).to_h
```

**#2**

```
def default_classroom(students, default_class)
  students.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[s] = default_class }
end
```

**#3**

Depending on your application, you may need only specify the hash's default value (and not add a key-value pair for each student). After reviewing the documentation for [Hash#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new), you might think this would be done as follows:

```
h = Hash.new(default_class)
  #=> {}
```

Then:

```
h["Billy-Bob"] == "Real Analysis"
```

evaulates to:

```
"Roofing 101" == "Real Analysis"
  #=> false
```

but the hash remains empty:

```
h #=> {}
```

Instead, initialize the hash with a block, like this:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=default_class }
  #=> {}
```

Then:

```
h["Billy-Bob"] == "Real Analysis"
```

again evaulates to:

```
"Roofing 101" == "Real Analysis"
  #=> false
```

but now:

```
h #=> {"Billy-Bob"=>"Roofing 101"}
```